# Can I identify if the a traffic is coming from facebook or somewhere else to log AddToCart Event Or Purshes Event on Facebook Pixels

Tags: reactjs, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-pixel, facebook-events

To describe more the issue, I have a business manager account on Facebook and I have implemented everything as it should using `React`, my problem is when the event AddToCart is firing the count increases on Facebook analytics for AddToCart; event tho the user is coming lets from google or any other social media.

**Is it applicable to only limited the events to be firing only if traffic comes from Facebook?**

Root.tsx

```
ReactPixel.init('PIXEL ID', null, {
    autoConfig: true,
    debug: true,
})
ReactPixel.pageView()
```

on add to cart button a fire this action

```
 ReactPixel.fbq('track', 'AddToCart', {
                contents: [{ id: action.payload.sku, quantity: 1 }],
                content_type: 'product',
                value: action.payload.price,
                currency: 'USD',
            })
```

any advice would be helpful!

Comment: I don't think there is any necessity to do that; never heard of anyone attempting it either. Figuring out whether the user's path to your site somehow went "via Facebook", is their business on their end.

Comment: @CBroe I think the default event such as page view can be triggered Via Facebook itself, I thought that I can implement it through Facebook business instead of from coding.